# what will be the java regex to Split a string based the last occurance of an unescaped @ character

Tags: java, regex, string, split

What will be the regex pattern to split a string based on the last occurance of an un-escaped `@` character ?

For eg:

- `Path1\\P@ath2\\Path3\\File1\\@12.1234wer@tjava\\@rep\o1`  - should split using the 3rd `@` symbol
- `Path1\\Path2\\Path3\\File1\\@12.1234wertjava\\@repo1@`    - should split using the last `@` symbol
- `Path1\\Path2\\Pat@h3\\File1\\12.1234wertjava\\@rep\\o1`   - should split using the first `@` symbol

Comment: Format your question and show an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a negative lookbehind:

```
string.split("(?<!\\\\)@");
```

This splits `string` by all `@` which are not preceeded by a backslash. Here's a solution to split the string by the last `@` not preceeded by a backslash.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)(?<!\\\\)@(.*)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(string);
String[] parts = new String[2];
if (matcher.matches()) {
    parts[0] = matcher.group(1);
    parts[1] = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Comment: @stephen : Thanks . I have tried to split with **"@(?!.*@)"** (i guess this is a negative lookahead) earlier but it was matching the last @ , irrespective of whether it was followed by an \\ or not. Was not aware about a negative lookbehind. Even though negative lookbehind is what actually i need, is there any way to find the exact match using a negative lookahead or a positive lookahead ..?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but it would make less sense. The `@` is the actual character you want to match and not on which you want to place an assertion. In edge cases, you'd get different results. For example `(.*[^\\\\])(?=@)(.*)` keeps the `@` sign and works for your examples, but not for strings like `@test` where `@` is the first character and the last `@` without backslashes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex: `/[^\\]@/`. It takes the first `@` not preceded by `\`.

Then use your split function in the language you use (it seems to be Java, according to your tags, still you could have posted some code you tried) to split the string using this pattern.

Comment: This consumes the character before `@` when splitting and it doesn't work for strings starting with `@`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to split string last occurrence of @ ...

```
String filePath= "Path1\P@ath2\Path3\File1\@12.1234wer@tjava\@rep\o1";
int p=filePath.lastIndexOf(pattern.quote("@"));
String e=filePath.substring(p+1);
```

Comment: `String.lastIndexOf()` takes a normal String, not a pattern.